# Make Selenium obtain list of URLs from a .txt file

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I have a code that returns the title of a list of URLs. I'd like to flesh it out in a couple of ways.

This is the code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from time import sleep
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
display = Display(visible=0, size(800,600))
display.start()
urls = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com"]
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/geckodriver/geckodriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
for url in urls:
        try:
           driver.get(url)
           print(driver.title)
        except TimeoutException as e:
           print("Timeout")
driver.quit()
```

With this, I would like to do the following. First, instead of taking the list of urls like that, I'd like them to be picked up from a .txt.
Then, I also want it so that when it checks an individual URL, it waits for its title to go from "Loading..." to something else, and then print what it changed into. To do that, I've tried this:

```
while driver.title == 'Loading...':  
     pass
print(driver.title)
```

The problem here is that sometimes, the title will never change from "Loading...", so the program will be stuck there forever. I want to have it so that if after 10 seconds, it hasn't changed yet, it goes onto the next url from the list, after printing "Title didn't load."

There is one last thing I'd like to add that I'm not sure how to. It prints the title with "print(driver.title)". I would like a number to be added after the title ("print(driver.title), "number").
The reason behind this number is to know the how many URLs it has gone through so far, but it doesn't start at 1. It would start at a higher number, like 50. This means that on the 5th url, it should be "title of url, 55." How could I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated script with your requirements.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from datetime import datetime

# this method will check the driver title after the specified interval seconds for a given max time in seconds
def wait_until_browser_loaded(interval, maxTime):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    elements = []
    while (datetime.now() - start_time).seconds < maxTime:
        time.sleep(interval)
        if driver.title != 'Loading...':
            return

display = Display(visible=0, size(800,600))
display.start()
# open and readlines from external input file
urlsFile = open("urls_file_path_goes_here", "r")
urls = urlsFile.readlines() # use this if you want to enter urls in different lines
#urls = urlsFile.read().split(",") # use this if you want to enter comma separated urls.

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/geckodriver/geckodriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
titleAppendNumber = 50
for url in urls:
        try:
            driver.get(url)

            title = driver.title
            if title == "Loading...":
                wait_until_browser_loaded(5, 10)
            if title == "Loading...":
                print ("Title Load" + " - " + str(titleAppendNumber))
            else:
                print (title + " - "+ str(titleAppendNumber))
            titleAppendNumber +=1
        except TimeoutException as e:
           print("Timeout")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as being able to timeout after 10 seconds if title has not changed, I can offer you what I use with java.  I know you are using python, but this is what I have to show.  You should be able to switch out the appropriate python syntax

```
def timeExpired = false

def timeoutPeriod = new TimeDuration(0, 0, 10, 0)

def timeStart = new Date()

def titleFound = false

def title

while(!titleFound && !timeExpired){ //While title is not found AND time has not expired run loop

    try{

        title = driver.title

        titleFound = title != "Loading..."

        if(!titleFound){  //No need to check if time expired if title has been found, so only checking if it hasn't

            timeExpired = TimeCategory.minus(new Date(), timeStart) > timeoutPeriod

            if(timeExpired){

                title = "Title didn't load"
            }
        }                   
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        //Handle the exception
    }
}

print(title)
```

To feed in URL's from a text file separate URL's by commas and read in the contents:

```
text_file = open("filename.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
```

I don't have python up and running to confirm that this is exact, but you can then loop through the lines and pass in the url this way and navigate the driver like you are already doing.

Lastly, to add a counter to your print out, you just need to setup a counter variable before you start looping through your URL's to start at whatever number you want.

```
counter = 50
```

Then inside your loop, you will increment each time by 1:

```
counter += 1
```

To add this to your print out, you can do this:

```
print(title + " " + str(counter))
```

The syntax may not be perfect, but it should be close.